# DataRow which is added is not going to be delete doing table.Rows[i].Delete()?

Tags: delete-row, datarow, rowstate

Why is that? The state of the datarow is added. When I delete the row the state is unchanged. Why not deleted? That's the reason my Delete Store Procedure is never called!

edit: the datarow is freshly added and then I try to delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

show your code please. my test shows that everything works fine:

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        Console.WriteLine(dr.RowState);
        dr.Delete();
        Console.WriteLine(dr.RowState);
```

output is:

```
        Added
        Detached
```

Comment: why is it detached? should it be not deleted?

Comment: @Lisa it is detached because previously it was added and state change was not accepted. if you first do `dt.ApplyChanges()` state will be Unchanged, if you delete it, it will be `Deleted`.